# How to give a permanent url to API gateway in Localstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, localstack

I'm using a localstack for local AWS development. The lambdas are exposed via API Gateway.
Whenever localstack is restarted (or when it is started for the first time on another machine) I have to create that gateway again and it's gonna have a new generated ID.

Like this console output:

```
endpoints:
  http://localhost:4566/restapis/0ulz03h9kk/local/_user_request_
```

How can I make this URL look pretty, so I could have a simple frontend startup script? Or at least, is there a way to make that id `0ulz03h9kk` somewhat hardcoded?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom API ID using tags on api-gateway setup in localstack.

Per the [API Gateway LocalStack docs](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/apigateway/#custom-ids-for-api-gateway-resources-via-tags):

> You can assign custom IDs to API Gateway REST and HTTP APIs using the *custom_id* tag during resource creation. This can be useful to ensure a static endpoint URL for your API, simplifying testing and integration with other services.
>
> To assign a custom ID to an API Gateway REST API, use the create-rest-api command with the `tags={"_custom_id_":"myid123"}` parameter. The following example assigns the custom ID "myid123" to the API:

```
awslocal apigateway create-rest-api --name my-api --tags '{"_custom_id_":"myid123"}'
{
    "id": "myid123",
    ....
}
```

> You can also configure the protocol type, the possible values being HTTP and `WEBSOCKET:`

```
awslocal apigatewayv2 create-api \
  --name=my-api \
  --protocol-type=HTTP --tags="_custom_id_=my-api"                                                                                                                   
{
    "ApiEndpoint": "my-api.execute-api.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566",
    "ApiId": "my-api",
    "Name": "my-api",
    "ProtocolType": "HTTP",
    "Tags": {
        "_custom_id_": "my-api"
    }
}
```